# Node.JS: What is the best way to implement ORM-style models that use API endpoints as data sources?

Tags: node.js, rest, orm, microservices

I'm implementing a microservice-based environment with separate data services for each DB.

However, in my management service (the business logic service that calls the data services), I would like to find a way to relate results from one endpoint to another without having to manually declare / write the same http requests over and over.

What I had envisioned was something similar to an ORM, i.e Sequelize, Bookshelf, etc., but instead of declaring a model attribute that links another TABLE using hasMany or belongsTo etc., it would link a specific data service API endpoint data source.

Thanks for your time,
Chris